# Temporary pause/disable background updater

Tags: windows-7, updates

Is there any program in Windows 7 that can pause or disable background updaters?

The reason I would like to do this is because I have an old computer, and when I watch a video in VLC and background updaters like Chrome or Windows Update start, it starts to lag in VLC and it becomes unwatchable. It is very annoying.

So the best would be if there is some program that can temporarily stop all background updaters when a certain program like VLC is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file with

```
net stop wuauserv
pause
net start wuauserv
```

This would stop the Windows Update service, wait for input (this is when you can watch VLC), and then start the service again.

Or, you could even have a `vlc.bat` with:

```
net stop wuauserv
vlc.exe
net start wuauserv
```

This way VLC would be started automatically and the service would be restarted when you close VLC.